# How to get shortcut target path with InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup, target, shortcut

**How to get shortcut target path with InnoSetup?
i want to get target path from a shortcut file with Innosetup.
is possible?**

Comment: TLama's provided you with an answer already, but depending on WHY you want to do this there might be an easier way.  For example, if you're trying to read the location where an application is installed, it's easier and more reliable to read the registry.  (If you're trying to read the location where YOUR application is installed, it's easiest to ask Inno.)