# Delete files/shortcuts matching a file mask on uninstall

Tags: inno-setup

I have created a shortcut named `Myapp` in the desktop. My installed app changes that shortcut, if I choose to others languages, for example: Spanish or French. Then the shorcut name changes to: `Myapp Spanish` or `Myapp French`.

That s why Inno Setup can not detect it on uninstall. And this doesn't work wither :

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{commondesktop}\Myapp*.ink";`
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's exactly why Inno can't delete it - because it doesn't know about it after you rename it. As you seem to know this already, what exactly is your question? The uninstaller can't possibly remove files it doesn't know exist, and it can't know about the shortcut you renamed because it didn't install the shortcut you renamed.

Comment: @KenWhite Cant i delete it by omitting the full name? for exemple Myapp* intead of Myapp Spanish, or at least using some cmd parameter on uninstall?

Comment: Not using the uninstaller, because it doesn't use wildcards. It will only uninstall files it installed, and it didn't install the renamed file. Why aren't you using Inno to install the shortcut based on the language (in which case it can uninstall it) rather than renaming it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete files matching a mask on uninstall, you can use:

```pascal
[Code]

function DeleteWithMask(Path, Mask: string): Boolean;
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  FilePath: string;
begin
  Result := FindFirst(Path + '\' + Mask, FindRec);
  if not Result then
  begin
    Log(Format('"%s" not found', [Path + '\' + Mask]));
  end
    else
  begin
    try
      repeat
        FilePath := Path + '\' + FindRec.Name;
        if not DeleteFile(FilePath) then
        begin
          Log(Format('Error deleting "%s"', [FilePath]));
        end
          else
        begin
          Log(Format('Deleted "%s"', [FilePath]));
        end;
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    Log('Deleting shortcuts')
    DeleteWithMask(ExpandConstant('{commondesktop}'), 'Myapp*.ink');
  end;
end;
```

*(I'm not sure, what `.ink` is about, though)*

---

Safer would be to iterate all shortcut files in the folder (desktop), deleting only those that point to your application.

See my answer to [Check for existence of a shortcut pointing to a specific target in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34220914/850848).

---

If I understand your question correctly, your application can already identify the correct shortcut file (as it seems to rename or delete the old shortcut, when the language changes). In that case, consider adding the "uninstall shortcut" functions to the application itself. Make the application process (undocumented) command-line switch to delete the shortcut (e.g. `/DeleteShortcut`). And use that from [`[UninstallRun]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Parameters: "/DeleteShortcut"; RunOnceId: "DeleteShortcut"
```